# Crossword with given grid and words

Tags: c++, algorithm, crossword

I have a crossword grid, for example

```
+-----+
|  *  |
|     |
+-----+
```

and list of words

```
a
ababa
bb
cc
ba
bb
ca
cb
```

Every word must be used. The goal is finding all variants how this crossword can be solved, in this case there are two variants -

```
bb*cc
ababa
```

and

```
cc*bb
ababa
```

Some more complex crosswords looks like that for example:

```
+-----+
|   * |
|     |
|    *|
|   * |
|  * *|
|  *  |
|     |
+-----+
```

with a list of 20 words etc.

I was trying to create algorithm to solve this kind of problem, but without succes. Can someone help me?

Comment: Images would make more sense here. What is your first example ? A single alphabet crossword ?

Comment: try exhaustive search with backtracking. if you pick the next move wisely, it will be quite fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note, that even determining if a crossword is "solveable" using the given dictionary is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard)<sup>1</sup>, so even determining if there is 0 or more solution cannot be done polynomially ([unless P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)).

Thus, the alternative is using an [exhaustive search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) solution - just try all possibilities to "place" the words, and then verify if this solution is valid.

**Pseudo code:**

```
solve(words,grid):
   if words is empty:
       if grid.isValidSolution():
          print grid as a possible solution
          return
   for each word in words:
       candidate<- grid.fillFirstSpace(word)
       solve(words\{word},candidate)
```

---

(1) Reference: [Is P equal to NP](http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~rbkmax001/project.pdf) section 3.3